# Spring AOP: Advice not executing for method with custom annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-aop

I have created a custom annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface ValidateBeforeBuild {
}
```

And an aspect as:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class AspectForBuildInBuilders {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AspectForBuildInBuilders.class);

    @Before("@annotation(validateBeforeBuild )")
    public void validateBusinessModelAdvice(JoinPoint jp, ValidateBeforeBuild validateBeforeBuild ) throws Throwable {
        LOGGER.info("Executing class: {}", jp);
    }
}
```

I have a `build()` that is marked with above annotation. When I am trying to call the `build()`, I am not getting the log message from the `validateBusinessModelAdvice()`. I also have `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` in one of the configuration classes. Am I missing something? Is there any more information required?

Comment: is the build in a class implementing an interface, is it inherited? I have this config in my project, which works: @Before(value = "@annotation("annotations.methodBased.BeforeMethod) && atExecution()")
    public void beforeMethod(final JoinPoint jPoint) throws Throwable {
try with adding the && atExecution()

Comment: I asked about the interface of parent class, since I've noticed that if it is, and your annotation takes parameters, it would only take if the original (in interface or parent class) method definition was marked with the annotation

Comment: Yes it is. Its in a class that implements a `Functional Interface` called `IBuilder<T>`

Comment: well ... I managed to work-around that issue by creating (for each implementation) a seperate class, that made sure my original class only passed the method call to that class, add the annotation to the method definition there. maybe that can help, though I'm not sure I've explained it clearly enough

Comment: did you also enable annotation-config? I'll try your annotation in my code. see if there's a problem on my side

Comment: @Stultuske Yes, I have done that as well

Comment: @Stultuske I have also tried above things that you suggested but it does not work. Any more clues?

Comment: I'm now trying it in some of my (working) code. the configuration is a bit different, but still might help me find something

Comment: It works for me .. only difference I immediately see, is my config is done in xml, only the aop is done by annotations

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162494/discussion-between-prashant-and-stultuske).

Comment: The information you provide is insufficient to reproduce the problem. Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), either here by editing your question, adding e.g. the interface, its implementation etc. or a full GitHub project. It is hard to debug an AOP-related issue if we only have the aspect, but not the code targeted by it.

Answer (score 0):

You defined your annotation as `ValidateBeforeBuild` and in your aspect you specified `validateBeforeBuild` (notice the upper `V` in your annotation)

Try changing

```
@Before("@annotation(validateBeforeBuild)")
```

for

```
@Before("@annotation(ValidateBeforeBuild)")
```

Comment: not necessary, it seems to be configured to point to the instance of the annotation which is passed as parameter, next to the JoinPoint, then it is supposed to be the name of the parameter, which is the case